# How to map a class via jdbc template

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

A table contains three columns: `Order, Item and price` which i access via `Jdbc Template` and trying to map with DTO.

```
Order   Item    Price
101    "xyz"    100
101    "Pqr"    150
101    "abc"    125 
102    "any"    200
102    "one"    101
```

I can map the above table with my dto with as below,

```
public class myDTO{
   String Order; // Order number
   String Item;  // item name  
   String price; // item price
   //getter-setter below
}
```

But i want to map the table in such a way where i would able to link an order against all Items and price which has common Order Number. I am just giving a plain idea of expected DTO class but not able to map.

```
public class requiredDTO{
   String order;    
   List<String> value;
   List<String> price;
//getter setter below
}
```

Comment: @RomanC Spring framework and mysql as database.

Comment: I didn't ask you about spring framework or any database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want either of your solutions... What you want (IMHO is the following)

```
public class Order {
    private long id;
    private Set<Item> items;
}

public class Item {
    private String name;
    private long price;
}
```

Use a ResultSetExtractor to create the `List<Order>`.

```
public OrderResultSetExtractor implement ResultSetExtractor<List<Order>> {
    public List<Order> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
        Order current = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            long orderId = rs.getLong(1);
            String itemName = rs.getString(2);
            long price = rs.getLong(3);
            if (current == null || current.getId() != orderId) {
                current = new Order();
                current.setId(orderId);
                orders.add(current);
            }
            current.getItems().add(new Item(itemName, price));
        }
        return orders;
    }
}
```

Something along these lines.

Answer (score 3):

Use 'BeanPropertyRowMapper' your columns name must match property names of MyDTO.

```
getJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT Order, Item, Price FROM your_table", new BeanPropertyRowMapper(MyDTO.class));
```

Then i recommend you to do your group logic later in java.

Good Luck!

Comment: please give me hint on group logic, as i got stuck in this part.